# Nesting for loops in Nuxt and displaying errors based on value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, object, nuxt.js

I've got a form that takes 3 input codes. First my project checks if the codes meet regex validation then are sent to the backend. I have a catch in my hero for the response and my issue is filtering through the error messages for the specific input code. My goal is to display an accurate error like {{this.form.code1.error }} if that input fails. I have various possible responses that I am trying to match.

My (e) object looks like this

```
    {
        "message": "code not found",
        "path": [
            "validate"
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "code": "CODE_NOT_FOUND",
            "value": "VBJCBGB6JJ"
        }
    },
    {
        "message": "code not found",
        "path": [
            "validate"
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "code": "CODE_NOT_FOUND",
            "value": "HH6F3JPMWF"
        }
    },
    {
        "message": "code not found",
        "path": [
            "validate"
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "code": "CODE_NOT_FOUND",
            "value": "4FHRXE2GGN"
        }
    }
]
```

and I am trying to dissect and map the values with this function

```
  showErrors(e) {
      let valid = true
      console.log(e)
      e.forEach((e) => {
        console.log('inside for each')
        if (e.message === 'code not found') {
          this.form.code1.valid = false
          valid = false
          this.form.code1.error =
            'Invalid code. Try again or see FAQ’s for help.'
          } 
        if (e.message === 'code used') {
          this.form.code2.valid = false
          valid = false
          this.form.code2.error = 'Code has already been redeemed.'
        } else {
          this.form.code1.valid = true
          this.form.code1.error = ''
        }
        return valid
      })
```

here is my template for referece

```
        .form-wrapper
          .row
            .input-container
              input(type="text" name="Code 1" placeholder="Code 1" v-model="form.code1.value" :class="{ error: form.code1.valid === false}" minlength="10").check
              //- .error-msg(v-if="form.code1.valid === false") {{form.code1.error}}
            .input-container
              input(type="text" name="Code 2" placeholder="Code 2" v-model="form.code2.value" :class="{ error: form.code2.valid === false}" minlength="10").check
              //- .error-msg(v-if="form.code2.valid === false") {{form.code2.error}}
            .input-container
              input(type="text" name="Code 3" placeholder="Code 3" v-model="form.code3.value" :class="{ error: form.code3.valid === false}" minlength="10").check
              //- .error-msg(v-if="form.code3.valid === false") {{form.code3.error}}
          .row
            .select-container
              select(v-model="form.retailer.value" :class="{ selected: form.retailer.value !== '', error: form.retailer.valid === false }")#select
                option(value="" disabled selected) Where did you shop? 
                option(v-for="option in stores") {{ option.text }}
              .error-msg(v-if="form.retailer.valid === false") {{form.retailer.error}}
              .error-msg(v-if="form.code1.valid === false") {{form.code1.error}}
              .error-msg(v-if="form.code2.valid === false") {{form.code2.error}}
            .cta.bg-blue-dark.inline-block.cursor-pointer.disabled#submit(@click="onSubmit" :disabled="!valid" class='hover:bg-blue-500 md:mt-7' type='submit') {{ buttonText }}
```

I feel like I am missing a connection here. Id like to be able to display either "code already redeemed" or "invalid code" or "code not know" or whatever the error coming back is but relevant to that code entry. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have the backend group these by the form element name so the key of the top level object is the field name, and each field name has many errors. this will create the connection

Comment: Is there any way of doing it from within this function or at the very least the fronted? @Ohhodwhy